# Enterprise Library Validation Block - Validate nullable properties?

Tags: validation, null, enterprise-library

I am trying to come up with a validation for a nullable property, like int.

Example

```
[RangeValidator(0, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 1, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive)]
int? Age { get; set; }
```

However if I set `Age` to null validation fails because it doesn't fall in the range, I know I need an `[ValidatorComposition(CompositionType.Or)]` as well, but what else should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the IgnoreNulls attribute:

```
[IgnoreNulls()]
[RangeValidator(0, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 1, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive)]
int? Age { get; set; }
```

Comment: This works as long as the validation passes.  If it fails, the resulting ValidationResults will contain an OrCompositeValidator with the RangeValidator as one of the nested ValidationResults, as pointed out by Paul.  There is an alternative - see my answer below.

Comment: -1 because I believe @Philippe's answer is more effective. Though I also think this is a significant oversight in the VAB.

Comment: I tried it with Enterprise Library 5.0 and it seems to work fine now - there is just one ValidationResult (with empty nested results) for failure and no ValidationResults for null values. Maybe Microsoft fixed the IgnoreNulls behavior.

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr. Downvoting because someone else have a better answer is not cool nor nice.

Answer (score 7):

While the `IgnoreNulls` attribute can be added, it leads to convoluted `ValidationResults` when validation results are returned.  This is because the validation block implicitly wraps the validators into an `OrCompositeValidator` - the property can be null OR it can be an integer in the range specified.

When the validation fails, the top-level validation result is for the `OrCompositeValidator`.  To get the actual `RangeValidator` validation result, you now need to drill down into the `NestedValidationResults` property on the `ValidationResult` object.

This seems like a lot of work to process validation result messages, so it seemed to me that there had to be a better way.

Here is what I did.

1. I created a class called `IgnoreNullStringLengthValidator` that inherits from the `StringLengthValidator` (here you would inherit the `RangeValidator`).
2. Create all the constructors needed to support the base constructors.
3. Override the `DoValidate` method and check for a null value - here you would write:

   ```
   if (!objectToValidate.HasValue) return;
   ```
4. Make sure your next line of code calls `base.DoValidate(...)`.
5. Created an attribute class called `IgnoreNullStringLengthValidatorAttribute` that returns the new `IgnoreNullStringLengthValidator`. Here, you would create an `IgnoreNullRangeValidatorAttribute` class.

The resulting validation result is much more in line with what you'd expect because it does not nest your validators implicitly.

Comment: This works quite well for me. I don't get the .HasValue bit, but testing for null worked just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but then if the `RangeValidator` causes a `ValidationResult`, then for some reason I end up with two `ValidationResults`... one correctly for the range validation problem but then another cryptic one that says:

> The value is not null and failed all its validation rules for key Age.

This is silly, I don't EVER want the `IgnoreNulls` validator to cause a validation result! Its really there to modify the others, isn't it? Add this to the lack of real Validation inheritance and functionality when using polymorphism, and so so many other things, and there are so many "small" problems with the VAB attributes that I find it unusable for anything beyond the trivial.